# Using content blocks in Django Template

Tags: django

I am having an issue when trying to make a generic template that is then extended into a child template.

**Post.html**

```
{% extends "blog\blog_base.html" %}
{% block title %} The Blog {% endblock %}

{% block menu %}
{% endblock %}

<h1>The Blogs Index Page</h1>

{% block content %}
  <h2> Posts </h2>
   {% for post in latest_post_list %}
     <h3> {{ post.title }} </h3>
      <p> {{ post.body|linebreaks }} </p>
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**blog_base.html**

```
<body>
{% block menu %} 
{% for menu in menu %}
    {{ menu.page_name }}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
  <div class = "content">
   {% block content %} <p> Place Holder </p> {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
```

The block for the content works.

The block for the menu does not, it displays no `page_name` property of the `menu` object.

But if i insert ->

```
{% for menu in menu %}
    {{ menu.page_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

straight into the Post.html template, it works. Oh it also automatically makes the menu a list as well which confuses me. Why does it make a list with bullet-points and not just print out each menu object on its own line?

Answer (score 1):

By including the block tags in *Post.html*, you're overriding the menu in the base template. Remove the following from the post template:

```
{% block menu %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: So the only time i define a block in a child template is when i want different content than what the parent template provides?

Comment: Exactly. If you want to **add** to whatever is in the base template, you can use [`{% block.super %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance)